# Creating AppointmentItems in shared calendars - object not found exception

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-interop

I'm trying to create an application that allows users to create appointment items on a shared outlook calendar for our business using Outlook Interop (is that how you say that?).

The calendar resides within my account and I've given everyone permission who needs it. Those users are able create and modify the calendar without issue from their real Outlook clients. I've written the following function and it works perfectly when it's run **with my account logged in.** The moment I log out and into one of the other users accounts, it throws an exception.

```
Public Sub AddAppointment()
    Try
        Dim Application As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
        Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim RootFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim PlumbingCalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim Appointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem

        RootFolder = NS.Folders("myemail@ourdomain.com") 'exception here
        CalendarFolder = RootFolder.Folders("Calendar")
        FletcherCalendarFolder = CalendarFolder.Folders("Plumbing Tasks")
        Appointment = FletcherCalendarFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment")

        'with/end with guts that define the appointmentitem here

        Appointment.Save()

        MessageBox.Show("An event for this due date was added to the calendar.")

        Application = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The event for this due date could not be added to the calendar. The following error occurred: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The exception gets thrown when I try to set RootFolder - says that 'The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found.' The fact that it works when the calendars owner is logged in makes me believe I'm not understanding how I should be getting the folders from a different account. Am I close? I am aware of the recipient object and creating and later resolving it with `Outlook.Namespace.CreateRecipient`, as well as `NameSpace.GetShareDefaultFolder`, but every combination of those I've tried has failed in the exact same way. I feel like I'm missing something silly.

Comment: The error means the top level (store) folder cannot be found. Are you sure that is how Outlook displays that mailbox? If you loop through the NS.Folders collection, what store names are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get this one working (FeelsGoodMan). I ditched the idea of getting the folder of my calendar the previous way when I found out about `Outlook.NameSpace.GetFolderFromID`. EntryID's are apparently unique identifiers for Outlook Objects(? Don't quote me.) By putting a watch on what folders did work I was able to get the EntryID of the Calendar, and then by using `GetFolderFromID` I was able to get a working folder in my code.

```
Public Sub AddAppointment()
    Const ENTRYID As String = "IdIGotFromWatch"
    Try
        Dim Application As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
        Dim NS As Outlook.NameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Dim Appointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem

        CalendarFolder = NS.GetFolderFromID(ENTRYID)

        Appointment = CalendarFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment")

        'with/end with guts that define the appointmentitem here

        Appointment.Save()

        Application = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The event for this due date could not be added to the calendar. The following error occurred: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Edit: I think it should be said that this solution will only work for me if the Calendar/Folder stays where it is and doesn't move. If I understand right, if the Calendar is ever relocated the EntryID will also change. I'm not sure what else will trigger a change in the ID (renaming perhaps? etc.), but I don't see why I couldn't just update the ID to reflect the change in the future. This works for me.